# Does Google App Engine Support PHP?

Tags: php, google-app-engine

Does Google App Engine support PHP?

I mean can I put my PHP projects there so that they are executable there?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We just announced PHP support at Google I/O. Go [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/) for the documentation and [here](https://gaeforphp.appspot.com/) to sign up to have an app whitelisted.

Comment: Nice video you did. Just wrote [a little quick review and some comments](http://hakre.wordpress.com/2013/05/18/php-on-google-app-engine-quick-first-review/), and maybe you can share where to report issues (see the iconv/domdocument problem).

Comment: Thanks for the post - nice write up. Add your extension list to our issue tracker (https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/entry?template=Feature%20request for example) and add Language-PHP to the tags and I'll do my best.

Answer (score 5):

Not directly, but apparently indirectly through the Java support using [Quercus](http://quercus.caucho.com). It's not clear, though, whether that really is a viable replacement. I would want to test this very thoroughly before running any production software that way.

Make sure you read all the feedback in the related SO question: [Is Quercus a viable replacement for PHP in Java environments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/777356/is-quercus-a-viable-replacement-for-php-in-java-environments)

A Blog entry with Installation instructions is [here](http://www.webdigi.co.uk/blog/2009/run-php-on-the-google-app-engine/).

Answer (score 2):

Newer package to install PHP on GAE can be found from: http://php-apps.appspot.com/

Tutorials and tips about using OpenID and OAuth can be found from same place.

Answer (score 1):

According to this bug: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=13 Google just announced direct support for PHP in GAE.

Answer (score 1):

Google App Engine (GAE) is open for everyone officially http://googlecloudplatform.blogspot.in/2013/10/google-app-engine-php-runtime-now-available-to-everyone.html

Continue reading on "Google App Engine (GAE) PHP tutorial in windows. Getting started with hello world example. GAE development and deployment" at http://www.tinywall.info/2013/10/12/google-app-engine-php-windows-getting-started-hello-world-example-gae-development-deploy/