# cakephp on google cloud

Tags: php, google-app-engine, cakephp

I found this question which is pretty old: [Is it possible to deploy cakephp applications on google app engine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9774182/is-it-possible-to-deploy-cakephp-applications-on-google-app-engine)

Some people stated, that it's most likely at least complicated - someone in the comments stated, that google supports php now(2013). Regarding to the google documentation: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/ it's still beta.

So my question is: did someone ever successfully deploy a cakephp application on google app engine? Is it now(2015) possible to deploy a app there without too much problems?

Answer (score 2):

"officialy" the CakePHP is not supported. You may find several steb-by-step howto's where is the deployment explained:

- http://dev-mcconnell.blogspot.sk/
- http://aymanrb.blogspot.sk/2013/05/cakephp-deployment-on-google-app-engine.html

However, when our customer requested to have CakePHP within his AppEngine, we decided to deploy Google Compute Engine linux VPS with some limited resources (you do not need that much resources if you do not expect huge amount of visitors), and we installed Apache, PHP and MySQL onto this VPS and we run CakePHP application from there.

So generally, the use case above is not an AppEngine deploy, but a deploy within Google Cloud services.

Comment: "The mails for example won't work with SMTP or normal mail function, the logging won't work with File engine all folder and file utility classes will not function and few other stuff. It is important to bear in mind that this is a preview release and I expect things to change dramatically a lot in the near future." ... yeah i stopped over a lot of posts like this - but most of them are from 2013, can't believe that nothing has changed since then

Comment: I guess this is the reason we choosed to deploy it as a VPS - once it is VPS you can install i.e. Postfix or anything else you want. But the pricing may differ.

Comment: Lots have things have changed since then - for example mail() just works out of the box - for example the solar impulse web site is CakePHP on App Engine. Also not sure where the "officially its not supported" statement comes from.