# Is Quercus (Java) faster than native PHP?

Tags: java, php, apache, tomcat, quercus

If so, why? (Or maybe the better question is 'when'?)

I've found some scattered comments, such as in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/777356/is-quercus-a-viable-replacement-for-php-in-java-environments), which seem to indicate that Quercus may actually offer some performance advantages over native PHP.

I am looking to use a Tomcat/Quercus configuration instead of an Apache/PHP one. (I need a Java servlet container and the alternative would be to use context filtering in Apache.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [their page](http://www.caucho.com/resin-3.0/quercus/#PHP-Users):

> Performance: Quercus outperforms a straight mod_php implementation by about 4x (for Mediawiki and Drupal). Quercus roughly matches PHP performance with accelerators like APC.

So if they claim they "match" PHP's performance with APC, then it's probably slightly slower.

Comment: That's probably true. Although the reason I personally ended up going with native PHP is that Quercus just didn't handle the PHP right. It certainly was not my experience that you can pass (working) PHP code to Quercus and expect it to work as is. (It may be something easy to fix, but I was not up to the task.)